# Opening a UserControl using multithreading to avoid UI Freeze VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, user-interface, user-controls, freeze

I'm a beginner. I've done a lot of research about Backgroundworker/Multithreading, but I still don't know what to do. My problem is the following:

I have a MENU (Which contains just a collection of colored buttons). When one of them is called (Btn), the button opens a new "UserControl". But it takes a long time to load, so the UI freezes for many seconds. I just want to avoid that. I want to show a Loading CircularProgressBar on top of my MENU while the UserControl loads and keeping the UI responsive during the loading.

The button's code :

```
 Private Sub Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn.Click

MainForm.ShowModalPanel(New UserControl1, DevComponents.DotNetBar.Controls.eSlideSide.Bottom)

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add proper tags. Otherwise no is going to discover your question.

Comment: you should also add a language tag